# Create separate Network for testing purpose

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012, dhcp-server

I have installed Windows Server 2012 on a VM (ESXi) for testing/learning purpose and I also like to install DHCP Server as well but this will conflict with my ISP router and I don't want to disable DHCP from my router.

How do I create a separate network but still have access to internet?

I have two Ethernet ports on my server, Eth0 is connected to a switch via ISP router. Eth1 is not plugged.

- Eth0 - vSwitch0
- Eth1 - vSwitch1

The DC is set to Eth1 and I have created separate network on Windows network setting (IP: 10.0.0.5, subnet mask:  255.0.0.0).

However, when I tried to config the DHCP Server -  it is asking me to enter the Gateway IP address from "New Scrope Wizard" - this is where I get stuck.

PS: I do not have vlan switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a physical network you'd separate the two with a router... Since this is virtualized I suggest trying a virtual router (like a pfSense VM, or even a Windows VM with RRAS).